# SimpleRoleProvider custom defined "UserID" foreign key constraint, possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following [this blog post](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/) to learn the new SimpleMemberProvider and SimpleRoleProvider features in latest release of asp.net MVC.

Instead of calling "UserId", I named it just "Id". Then, however, when I enabled the "SimpleRoleProvider" in web.config, I got error like "Foreign key 'fk_UserId' references invalid table 'MemberProfile'." it seems by default it's looking for UserId column to create foreign key constraint.

Is it possible to user something else rather than "UserId"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it gets it's name from it's initialization
Look for Filters

```
 WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Comment: It throws this error even if you specify the correct column name :/